# How do I send django object list to javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to django query to javascript.so I changed queries to list. I sended list to javascript.But list were not displayed by console log.

```
class Comment_List_TV(ListView):
      template_name = 'account/user_comment_list_tv.html'
      def get_queryset(self):
            Comment_list_query = list(Comment_tv.objects.none())
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                  Comment_list_query = list(Comment_tv.objects.filter(user=self.request.user))
            print(Comment_list_query)
            return Comment_list_query
```

Print display object list. But

```
    const mydata = "{{Comment_list_query}}";
    console.log(mydata);
```

Console log does not display django's object list.
why?
How do I send django object list to javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console log does return nothing because `Comment_list_query` in django template is called `object_list`, so you should use...

```js
const mydata = "{{ object_list }}";
console.log(mydata)
```

But it won't work, because you probably needs parsed values.

So, you should write view like this:

```py
@csrf_exempt
def get_comments(request):
    comment_list_query = list(Comment_tv.objects.all())
    return JsonResponse({'result': comment_list_query})
```

And receive it from AJAX call (for example using AJAX method from jQuery package).